# List to dict (subfolder)

Tags: python

Anyone can help me..
I've data list

```
namelist=['res/anim/satu.jpg','res/anim/dua.jpg','res/draw/logo.jpg','res/draw/img/bg.png','res/draw/img/fg.png']
```

how to transform to dict like this

```
{'res': {'anim':['satu.jpg', 'dua.jpg']},'draw': ['logo.jpg', {'img':['bg.jpg', 'fg.jpg']}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply build the structure:

```
result = {}

for name in namelist:
    parts = name.split('/')
    target = result
    for part in parts[:-2]:
        try:
            target = target.setdefault(part, {})
        except AttributeError:  # hit list leaf, add dictionary
            try:
                target = next(t for t in target if isinstance(t, dict))
            except StopIteration:
                target.append({})
                target = target[-1]
    try:
        target.setdefault(parts[-2], []).append(parts[-1])
    except AttributeError:  # hit list leaf, add dictionary
        try:
            target = next(t for t in target if isinstance(t, dict))
            target.setdefault(parts[-2], []).append(parts[-1])
        except StopIteration:
            target.append({parts[-2]: [parts[-1]]})
```

This gives:

```
{'res': {'draw': ['logo.jpg', {'img': ['bg.png', 'fg.png']}], 'anim': ['satu.jpg', 'dua.jpg']}}
```

but you really want to rethink the strategy of your structure. You'd have to search through the list for a mapping (in the exception handlers) otherwise.

Comment: you may also want to look at `os.walk` function to generate this path, if your list is generated by an actual listing of your filesystem.